# pip.main install fails with 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install few of the python packages from within a python script and I am using `pip.main(install)` for that. Below is code snippet

```
try:
    import requests
except:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', '-q', 'requests==2.0.1','PyYAML==3.11'])
    import requests
```

I have tried using importing main from pip._internal and using pipmain instead of pip.main() but it did not help.

I am on `pip version 9.0.1` and `python 2.7`

Comment: Is there a folder/file in your workspace with name pip. It might be possible that some other module/file is being imported. Check what is the output of pip.__file__ . It should point to the right location of pip.

Comment: @serbia99 I call a script with my own python interpreter which internally imports the module which has above snippet. So, I have my own pip and python both

Comment: i have similar problem recently , same thing happened following pip update to 10.0.1. i deleted the python/site-packages/pip/__pycache__  folder and downgrade it to 9.0.1. and it worked.  you might want to have a go.

Comment: thanks. Looks like that it is issue associated to pip version.

Answer (score 7):

pip Developers do not recommend calling pip from within the program.
And the pip.main() method has been removed from pip v10.
As an alternative method it is recommended to execute pip in subprocess.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/?highlight=_internal#using-pip-from-your-program

```
try:
    import requests
except:
    import sys
    import subprocess
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'requests==2.0.1', 'PyYAML==3.11'])
    import requests
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and just running the below command solved it for me:

```
easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 1):

The pip.main function was moved, not removed by pip devs. The highest voted solution here is not good.  Going from python -> shell -> python is not a good practice when you can just run the python code direct.  Try `from pip._internal import main` then you can use that main function to execute your pip calls like before.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is don't do this. Use `setup.py` or a straight import statement.

[Here is why this doesn't work with pip and how to get around it if necessary.](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)

`pip` affects the whole environment. Depending on who is running this and why, they may or may not want to install `requests` in the environment they're running your script in. It could be a nasty surprise that running your script affects their python environment.

Installing it as a package (using `python setup.py` or `pip install`) is a different matter. There are well-established ways to install other packages using `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`. It is also expected that installing a package will install its dependencies.  [You can read more in the python.org packaging tutorials](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/)

If your script has dependencies but people don't need to install it, you should tell them in the `README.rst` and/or `requirements.txt`.  **or** simply include the import statement, and when they get the error, they'll know what to do.  Let them control what environment installs which packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to install a lib if needed. It is convenient.

```
#%%
# IMPORTS

import pip

def import_or_install(package):
    try:
        __import__(package)
    except:
        import sys
        import subprocess
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
        __import__(package)

import_or_install("numpy")
import_or_install("matplotlib")

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#%%
# Your code

print("Hello")
```