# How do I install an older version of Pip in Pycharm when it keeps failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

Ok, so I'm having some trouble importing tweepy and textblob in Pycharm.

Before getting these errors I installed both textblob and tweepy using the following commands:

```
python3 -m pip install tweepy textblob
```

Which seemed to work fine. When I go into the Python3 shell and run:

```
import textblob
import tweepy
```

I'm able to enter a shell and those packages import correctly.

When I started writing my code in Pycharm, that's when the issue occurs, after the first 2 import statements as follows:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import sys, tweepy
```

I get the following errors:

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Unresolved reference 'textblob'
No module named 'tweepy'
```

I've done extensive research on Google and Stack Overflow and came to a conclusion that it's because of pip (at least I think but please correct me if I'm wrong). I tried installing an older version of pip in Pycharm by going to the Preferences > adding the package > pip but getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870594/pip-main-install-fails-with-module-object-has-no-attribute-main) it says that the "main" method is deprecated in pip 10.0.1, which is the version I'm running but it won't even let me install an older version, so I'm not sure what to do at this point.

I'm also running Python 3.6.1 if that helps. Would love to get better at troubleshooting and resolving errors! Any help would be great.

**EDIT**
Here's the full stack trace error when trying to install an older version of pip.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 184, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
    return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs)
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

**EDIT**
Still troubleshooting the issue and reading through this [post](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240), someone may find it helpful.

Comment: Are you definitely using the right interpreter in Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter?

Comment: yep, just checked. I'm using the correct interpreter version of 3.6.1. I also have a 2.7 version installed but it's not selected.

Comment: Also, weird thing is I can't uninstall pip in Pycharm as the button is disabled.

Comment: I suggest the use of the command line for updating the package manager `pip` (and also for installing any package) I've experienced many issues with the Pycharm -> preferences tool

In the cmd: `pip install --upgrade pip==<version>`

Comment: Hi @Eskapp, if I update from the command line is that supposed to update Pycharm? I've experienced so many issues with Pycharm too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this fix was A LOT easier than initially thought. I'm posting my answer just in case someone is banging their head on the same problem.
The fix in PyCharm was to go to Preferences > Updates. Then run the updates. In my update it indicated there was an issue with pip 10.0.1 and needed to be updated.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In pycharm run this command,

activate your ENV
and then **go to terminal inside pycharm**

then run this command,

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

To decrease version of a `library` you can use `python -m pip install --user --upgrade library==[version]`